# No channel id passed, notifications may not work. react-native-push-notifications

Tags: react-native, react-native-push-notification

Error: WARN  No channel id passed, notifications may not work.

[LOG]  createChannel returned 'false'

How to pass the channel id ?

Here's my code:

```
export const LocalNotification = () => {
    PushNotification.localNotification({
        autoCancel: true,
        bigText:
          'This is local notification demo in React Native app. Only shown, when expanded.',
        subText: 'Local Notification Demo',
        title: 'Local Notification Title',
        message: 'Expand me to see more',
        vibrate: true,
        vibration: 300,
        playSound: true,
        soundName: 'default',
        actions: '["Yes", "No"]'
    })
}

const startFunction = async () => {
  
  PushNotification.createChannel(
  {
    channelId: "channel-id-1",
    channelName: "My channel",
    channelDescription: "A channel to categorise your notifications",
    playSound: false, 
    soundName: "default",
    importance: Importance.HIGH, 
    vibrate: true, 
  },
  (created) => console.log(`createChannel returned '${created}'`) 
  );

  LocalNotification();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

PushNotification.createChannel(
{
channelId: "channel-id-1",
channelName: "My channel",
channelDescription: "A channel to categorise your notifications",
playSound: false,
soundName: "default",

```
          vibrate: true, 
        },
        (created) => console.log(`createChannel returned '${created}'`) 
        );
   
    PushNotification.localNotification({
        channelId : "channel-id-1",// this is where you need to add local notification
        autoCancel: true,
        bigText:
          'This is local notification demo in React Native app. Only shown, when expanded.',
        subText: 'Local Notification Demo',
        title: 'Local Notification Title',
        message: 'Expand me to see more',
        vibrate: true,
        vibration: 300,
        playSound: true,
        soundName: 'default',
        actions: '["Yes", "No"]'
    })
```